# Failed to find provider info for urbanairship.provider

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, urbanairship.com

I'm not sure this question is answerable, but I'm getting desperate so hopefully there is someone with more experience who may know what's going on. I've not used urbanairship before.

I've inherited a project and migrated it from eclipse to android studio. I could not get it to run in eclipse, but have managed to get it to run in android studio as much as it does when I download the app from the store (it's a very buggy app).

I've tried adding the urbanairship dependency in many different ways, from working with the original project using the migration process to android studio folders as they were handed over to  removing it altogether from the original project and importing it from scratch and every possible permutation between.

It will install onto the device, it doesn't crash, it also doesn't do most of what it's supposed to do, and the logcat (errors only) gives me this:

```
Failed to find provider info for xxxx.urbanairship.provider
- UALib: Failed to insert in UrbanAirshipProvider.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://xxxx.urbanairship.provider/preferences
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1203)
at com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipResolver.insert(UrbanAirshipResolver.java:77)
at com.urbanairship.PreferenceDataStore$Preference.writeValue(PreferenceDataStore.java:447)
at com.urbanairship.PreferenceDataStore$Preference.access$000(PreferenceDataStore.java:355)
at com.urbanairship.PreferenceDataStore$Preference$1.run(PreferenceDataStore.java:387)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

When I go to the link at `UrbanAirshipResolver.java:77` I get this window.

[image]

I attempt to choose source (I have attempted downloading, but yields no results), the jar is in the library, I select it.

[image]

It then shows 'attaching' indefinitely and will repeat the same error every time I run it.

[image]

This is between the application tags in the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
    android:authorities="xxxx.urbanairship.provider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:multiprocess="true"
    android:permission="xxxx.permission.UA_DATA"/>
```

It's like I'm missing a directory from the original project.

I'm at a total loss, at this stage, of what to do. If this is familiar to anyone, your help and guidance is gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it actually "xxx.urbanairship.provider" ? "xxx" should match the application ID. I would remove the eclipse style library version of Urban Airship and all manifest entries for Urban Airship. Then install it following http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html. It will automatically merge the manifest values properly. Make sure you set the application ID in the build.gradle file for the app's module.

Comment: If you can post your build.gradle file and your AndroidManifest.xml that would help me identify your issues.